# RoR relationship model where everyone in a group should be able to access the same info

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 3 models right now, Group, User and Asset.

How should I model it such that

1. User belongs to Group, Group has many users
2. Asset belongs to Group, Group has many asset
3. Every User in the Group have access to the asset, for example *@user.assets* will fetch assets' info

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need for anything fancy. Basic rails associations between the models will take care of everything.

To have a user access the group's assets, I'd recommend using `delegate`.

For more info on `delegate` check the [Rails Guide: Active Support Core Extensions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#method-delegation)

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  has_many :assets 
end

class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
  delegate :assets, :to => :group
end
```

Using delegate allows you to access assets using `@user.assets` as you asked.

Comment: Thanks! I will try it out later and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

In user.rb:

```
def assets
  return self.group.assets
end
```